# Auto-suggest entities using the Wikipedia API

Tags: semantic-web, wikipedia-api, autosuggest, linked-data

I want to provide an auto-suggest feature to my users, where they can choose from a list of known "things" from a semantic entity database.

I'm looking at using the Wikipedia Media API instead of setting up my own:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

There is an API tool for testing requests:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox

For example if a user likes cats:
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q146

The requests would be:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&prop=pageterms&list=&meta=&titles=C
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&prop=pageterms&list=&meta=&titles=Ca
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&prop=pageterms&list=&meta=&titles=Cat

The user would select Cat from the dropdown, and I would save the ID.

Is this a good approach? How could I improve it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Trying to have user inputs validated by a list of real things. To prevent a user entering sjakhajsfkh as an entry. It has to match a real thing e.g. wikipedia entry

Comment: Found this which helps:
https://codepen.io/luckyguy73/pen/GqPzZO?editors=0010#0

Comment: What is a good approach depends on the context, of which you haven't shared much. For example, are you okay with someone else determining what is "known"? Wikidata has a fairly large database, but it doesn't contain everything, and some things are omitted intentionally (e.g. due to not being important enough).

Comment: I'm presuming Wikipedia to be my moderator, only adding Things which are valid and not obscene etc. Rather than build that functionality on my end

Answer (score 1):

I managed to load autosuggestions using the Wikipedia REST api:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&gsrlimit=15&generator=search&origin=*&gsrsearch=
```

The Angular code:

```
this.resultsCtrl = new FormControl();
this.resultsCtrl.valueChanges
  .debounceTime(400)
  .subscribe(name => {
    if (name) {
      this.filteredResults = this.filterResults(name);
    }
  });

filterResults(name: string) {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    const displaySuggestions = function (response) {
      if (!response) {
        obs.error(status);
      } else {
        obs.next(Object.keys(response.query.pages).map(key => response.query.pages[key]));
        obs.complete();
      }
    };
    this.http.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&gsrlimit=15&generator=search&origin=*&gsrsearch='
      + encodeURI(name))
      .subscribe(displaySuggestions);
  });
}
```